# How to I secure API explore cloud endpoints by steps?

Tags: javascript, java

The API is a backend to a Web app and mobile app. I don't need user authentication. I simply need a way to secure access to this API.

I just need to ensure only web app and mobile app can talk to this backend and no one else.

Comment: I guess you mean webservices of some kind? If so you need some form of "user authentication" which might be your mobile app. This still would allow your app to be decompiled and thus doesn't provide high level security. It all depends on what you're actually trying to achive. What would happen if it was not your app that calls the services (if there is no authentication at all)?

Comment: i think you are referring to tokens isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed using Google Cloud Endpoints, what you want is easy to do.

You need to log into the developer console and go under API Manager -> Credentials. There you can generate access keys for each of your clients. Then you add those tokens to your endpoints using the provided annotations. You cloud endpoints will only serve requests that come from one of the clients you have specified.

Comment: Thank you for kind response. I don't knowledge about cloud endpoints. If you tell me step by step what I do.